# Can't connect with HTTPS but HTTP works fine

Tags: linux, apache, http, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to secure my we server using HTTPS and SSL/TLS to access my website. Going to the site by `www.-----.------.compute-1.amazonaws.com` works and the connection is successful. But when I try `https://www.-----.------.compute-1.amazonaws.com` chrome says "This site can’t be reached" "www.-----.------.compute-1.amazonaws.com refused to connect". I am using an Amazon Linux instance. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Is 443 port open for incoming traffic?

Comment: I added port 443 to my inbound rules security group. Not sure if it’s open on the Linux instance.

Comment: @met how do I open port 443 on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed an SSL certificate from a CA (certificate authority). I was using a self-signed certificate which doesn't work in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Typical problem. I am assuming some things here.

- You launched a EC2 (or something similar) Instance
- Didn't Open 443 port or Configure it further.
- Using port 80 for serving pages.

I think you got the answer. Check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/ssl-offload-enable-traffic-and-verify-certificate.html) out.

Comment: I got ```connect:errno=61``` when trying to openssl to port 443 via openssl

Comment: Is port 443 open on your instance? Check your security groups.

Comment: Yes it's open on my instance as an inbound rule in a security group. Still can't connect via https though.

Comment: Did you find out the reason I get this error number 61?

Comment: Would you mind posting security rule for 443 in the question? I am suspecting that, Inbound rule for that is only accepting local connections. Like [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067941/aws-port-in-security-group-but-cant-connect)

Comment: I found the issue! Posting an answer now!